# How can I pause java code running on server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications

How do I pause java code running on server ?

For example :

```
do {
  // do this

  // alright, now do this

  // wait for some time

} while(condition);
```

This code could be anything. Like it could be the part of an application that re tweets based on some interpretation .

Will it be right to use :

```
Thread.sleep(duration);
```

Comment: can you explain why would you want to do this? Since it's in a web application, you would be timing out the requests as well as tying the server thread in the pause state. I see no reasons to do this. You *can* use Thread.sleep(), but there are probably better ways to do what you're doing.

Comment: Either check some waiting condition in an inner loop and send the thread to sleep as long as this condition is true or aquire some lock within the loop which you can also aquire from some other place outside the loop such that it only continues once you release it.

Comment: Thread.sleep() and similar operations in other languages are usually not a good idea. Probably you can do what you want to do without using sleep. In this case sleep will block the server thread (or a whole process in some cases), and probably cause client timeouts, so I'll try to find a better way.

Comment: You can even explore about scheduledexecutor service as concurrency packages are easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping server threads is not a good way. Maybe you can use Timers for scheduled tasks instead.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html